# Negatively offset signal on op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, offset

I am simulating the use of a tl074 quad op-amp and i have configured one of the op-amps as a non-inverting op-amp, where R1=1 Meg and R2=4 Meg and the supply voltage is 9V. Every time i put a signal in, the output is always offset negatively. Is this how the op-amp is supposed to work? or are there more components to add to get just an amplified signal rather than a negatively offset amplified signal? This is basically the configuration i used below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNJeQJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the signal output that i get, Green being the input. Blue being the output.
[image]
Sorry if my terminology is wrong. Ill gladly fix my terminology if it is wrong.

Comment: Your text talks about R1 and R2, but your schematic shows Rs, Rf, and Rin. Please fix one or the other so that it's clear which resistor in the schematic you mean when you mention it in the text.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "offset negatively"? Give an example of an input, what output you expected, and what you actually got.

Comment: Now your text says you configured a non-inverting amplifier, but your schematic shows an inverting amplifier. Please make clear what was your actual circuit configuration.

Comment: When editing your post, you can click the circuit icon to use our schematic editor and put exactly the schematic you want, instead of trying to find a schematic online that is kinda sorta like what you built.

Comment: Gosh, sorry, i keep putting the wrong things, give me a bit

Comment: @ForeverLearningJP Take a look at the datasheet to find the bias currents for the opamp (may as well look at the offset current while you are at it.) Then compare these current magnitudes with the magnitudes of your resistors. What kind of voltage drop might be present? I've not looked. I just want to know if you've considered that factor.

Comment: @jonk, :0, I think thats it right there, I scaled down the values of the resistors and its working as intended now. Thanks man!

Comment: @ForeverLearningJP No problem. Just glad it helped clarify things. You should always see a red flag when seeing large-valued resistors. They can be used, of course. But it usually means closer thinking about what you are trying to do, and how.

Comment: This won't work anyway, you'll need something like +/-4.5 supplies.

Comment: Your circuit shows the op-amp powered by +9V only, but the graph shows output going down to -3V. This is impossible. Please show us the _real_ circuit that you used in the simulation! What frequency is the 100mV sine wave?

Comment: @BruceAbbott, The Circuit I provided is the same circuit that I have on ltspice which gave me that output. The input signal is 100mV at 1kHz.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Could I do that with a 9V supply, say put two resistors of same value in series across the 9V and center tap the resistors to get +4.5V and -4.5V?

Comment: "The Circuit I provided is the same circuit that I have on ltspice which gave me that output." - I reproduced your circuit in LTSpice and the output was (as expected) an almost constant +1.61V. What model were you using for the TL072?